# ruby sort array of different objects by property

Tags: ruby

I have array of different object with the same properties

```
class Report1 < ActiveRecord::Base


end
class Report2< ActiveRecord::Base

end
class Report3< ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

And  I select them like this:

```
@reports1 = Report1 .where(...)
@reports2 = Report2.where(...)
@reports3 = Report3.where(...)

 @reports_all = @reports1 + @reports2 + @reports3
```

How do I sort it by `date` field?

I tried to use .sort but got an error that these objects are different types

Answer (score 2):

Try this sort_by that handles nil values at the end:

```
@reports_all = @reports_all.sort_by{|report| [report.date ? 0 : 1, report.date]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sort_by`?

```
@reports_all = @reports_all.sort_by(&:date)
```

or

```
@reports_all.sort_by!(&:date)
```

Comment: `sort_by': comparison of Date with nil failed (ArgumentError)

Comment: ok. You have to choose if you want nil dates at the beginning or in the end of the array

Comment: let's say in the end

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong in a nutshell. Select and sort directly in the database:

```
@reports_all = ActiveBase::Connection.execute(<<-SQL
  (SELECT * FROM report1 WHERE ... 
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM report2 WHERE ... 
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM report3 WHERE ... )
  ORDER BY date
SQL
)
```